# Eager Loading Deeply into a Model with a Collection Property Whose Type is Inherited

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Visual Studio generated this great route for me, where I can load an entity:

```
// GET: api/Jobs/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Job))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetJob(int id)
{
    Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);

    if (job == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(job);
}
```

Here's the `Job` model this is based on:

```
public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        this.Regions = new List<Region>();
        this.Files = new List<JobFile>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public JobTypes JobType { get; set; }
    public int UserIDCreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int? UserIDAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public List<JobFile> Files { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; } // Lock for modification access
}
```

Here's the `JobFile` class, which `Job`s have a list of:

```
public class JobFile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Job_ID { get; set; }
}
```

and `Pdf`, a subclass of `JobFile`:

```
public class Pdf : JobFile
{
    public Pdf()
    {
        this.PdfPages = new List<PdfPage>();
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public List<PdfPage> PdfPages { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I hit that route, I'd like to eagerly load all the `Pdf`s for a `Job`, including their pages. I modified the route to look like this, and it works.

```
// GET: api/Jobs/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Job))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetJob(int id)
{
    Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);

    // Lookup the PDFs for this job and include their PdfPages
    List<JobFile> jobPdfs = db.Pdfs.Include(pdf => pdf.PdfPages).Where(pdf => pdf.Job_ID == id).ToList<JobFile>();

    // Attach the job files to the job
    job.Files = jobPdfs;

    if (job == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(job);
}
```

Is this the best way to eagerly load all these models? Could this somehow be collapsed into one statement? It seems right now it hits the database twice. Could I build off of the original

```
Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);
```

to load the `Pdf`s and their `PdfPage`s all in one query?

This [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82587/eager-load-additional-data-about-some-instructors) provided some helpful insight, but I'm not sure how I can capitalize on its conclusions. I think I need the `ToList<JobFile>()` (which according to the question does a trip to the database) because I actually need that data. So unless I can squash it into one more complicated Linq statement, perhaps it's unavoidable to make two trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you'd actually want to include subtypes. If `Job` had a collection of `Pdf`s, you could have done

> ```
> Job job = await db.Jobs
>                   .Include(j => j.Pdfs.Select(pdf => pdf.PdfPages))
>                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(j => j.Id == id);
> ```

But `Pdf` is a subtype, and EF doesn't support a syntax like

> ```
> Job job = await db.Jobs
>                   .Include(j => j.Files.OfType<Pdf>().Select(pdf => pdf.PdfPages))
>                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(j => j.Id == id);
> ```

So what you do is the only way to get the `Job` with `Pdf`s and `PdfPage`s.

There are some improvements to be made though:

- You can just load the child objects into the context without assigning them to `job.Files` yourself. EF will knit the entities together by *relationship fixup*.
- You can first check if the `Job` is found and then load the `Pdf`s.

Turning it into this:

```
Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);
if (job == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
else
{
    // Load the PDFs for this job and include their PdfPages
    await db.Pdfs.Include(pdf => pdf.PdfPages).Where(pdf => pdf.Job_ID == id)
        .LoadAsync();
}

return Ok(job);
```